# For an algebraic group $G$, elements in $[G,G](R)$ lies in $[(G(R')),(G(R'))]$ for a faithful flat $R'$ over $R$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

Let $G$ be an algebraic group over $k$ which is either smooth or affine. Then the derived group can be defined by the algebraic subgroup generated by the image of the morphism
$$G\times G \rightarrow G, (g,h)\mapsto ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$$
i.e. the minimal algebraic subgroup containing the image of the above morphism.

In the [note](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf) *Algebraic groups, The theory of group schemes of finite type over a field.* by Milne, 8.21(c), he says that $[G,G](R)$ consists of elements of $G(R)$ that lie in $[G(R'),G(R')]$ for some faithfully flat R-algebra $R'$.

The proof given in the note does not give the detail. Can anyone prove this proposition?

Comment: Milne says it follows from Proposition $8.20$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I just couldn't see how it follows from that proposition.

Comment: What does Proposition 8.20 say? And which part of the result are you having trouble with—that $[G, G](R) \subset G(R)$, or that it is not necessarily equal to $[G(R), G(R)]$?

Comment: @Jackson It is said that for a $k$-algebra $R$ and $x\in [G,G](R)$, there is a $k$-algebra $R'$ that is faithfully flat over $R$, such that the image of $x$ under the map $[G,G](R)\rightarrow [G,G](R')$ lies in $[G(R'),G(R')]\subseteq [G,G](R')$. I do not know why it is true.